# Z3 + boogie installation

Tags: z3, ipl

I am having some hard time getting the Boogie and Z3 to install on Windows 7 with Z3 version 4.3.2 from codeplex.
I've tried to install it like spec# by register.cmd command in prompt, but it doesnt work.
Can anyone tell me how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Boogie does not support Z3 version 4.3.  You need version 4.1 (see the Installation page on boogie.codeplex.com, which I just updated).

By the way, the register.cmd thing was purely a Spec# thing.

Comment: So i download and install z3 version 4.1. From microsoft research folder i took z3.exe and copied it to boogie binaries. Then i run boogie exe, but prompt appeared and dissappered momently. Should i add something like "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft research" to my PATH variable ?

Comment: The only thing that I found to work was to copy all the Z3 DLLs to the folder containing the Boogie executable.